# How to warm up cloud function instances at set time each week

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

During specific times each week the traffic on our app spikes by about 15,000 users. The spike is always predictable and at the same times every week. Currently I keep 100 instances warm all week for that spike for my cloud functions. Im trying to cut costs and I was wondering if I could spike the number of warm instances at a set time instead of keeping them warm all week.

I did come across this link for [configuring warm up requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configuring-warmup-requests?tab=node.js) but this seems like it would do it for all my functions, where I only need to warm up about 10% of them.

Ive already lowered the default warm instances to 0 for things that are not as time sensitive and lowered my important ones to only keep enough warm for the peak.

Comment: Do you think it may be possible to redeploy a cloud function with a specific set of parameters at some time before the peak hours, and redeploy it again (with another set of parameters) after the end of the peak hours?

Comment: How quick of a burst is this 15k-user spike? I'd imagine it would have to be rather sharp to be concerned about this. What percentage of the 15k would you surmise experience a cold start? Have you analyzed the logs and performed your own real-world testing to see how quickly the servers get hot? In other words, how much of a gap is there between request #1 and #15,000 in terms of execution time?

Comment: As suggested by @al-dann, you could redeploy the CLoud Functions every week with the min instance updated. It's the most efficient IMO. You can also imagine to create a new service, that publish thousands of dummy messages in PubSUb, and a pubsub push subscription that call your Cloud Functions HTTP endpoint. Like that you schedule the service just before (about 5 minutes) the spike and your instances will be already up and warm

Comment: @trndjc its not an instant spike, its over a few hours. My plan was going to be to warm up the servers a few hours before and then turn off the warm up requests a few hours after the spikes

Comment: You can try https://cloud.google.com/scheduler to set cron job to trigger cloud function  and warm it before peak time

Comment: How much testing or research have you done to conclude that you need a few hours to warm up cloud function servers? On the face of it, seems high.

Comment: @trndjc We don't necessarily need a few hours, that was just a precaution. We typically spike around 100 or so instances during the high load times. I recently inherited this code base and was told we keep 50 instances warm because the service used to crash with less than that during those times. During down times we need 0 instances.

Comment: Really, the cloud functions were actually throwing errors abundantly because of the traffic spike if you didn't pre-warm the VM? Are your functions v1 or v2? I know that v2 has done considerable work improving scalability. I wonder if these fixes are enough for your use case.

Comment: @trndjc they are V1, they were written about 4 years ago. I believe the CFs weren't throwing errors but they were timing out as they reach out to the 3rd party services. Have you done an upgrade from V1 to V2? Is it a huge lift?

Comment: I haven't upgraded to v2 yet because I don't have the need and it's still in beta through Firebase so when it becomes generally available (GA) I'll switch. But v2 is GA right now through GCP, so you can give it a try. I'd start there, personally. V2 added a new layer of concurrency which should substantially reduce the number of cold starts. However, because it's still in beta through Firebase, when it does encounter a cold start, it may take longer to warm up than v1, right now.